# R-splitting a data frame of factors with NA's

Tags: r

I have the a dataframe(df) which is imported from web. I am interested with the following column(colname) of df. The elements of colname are recognized as "factors". A sample from df is like below which also includes "NA"s:

```
colname
57 +0.10
55
NA
57,5 +2.00
56,5 +0.50
56,5
58
```

I would like to split the colname by "+" and get 3 numeric columns as below.
The desired output is:

```
colname1 colname2 total
57.00    0.10     57.10
55.00    0.00     55.00
NA       NA       NA
57.50    2.00     59.50
56.50    0.50     57.00
56.50    0.00     56.50 
58.00    0.00     58.00
```

which is also a data frame and the all there columns are numeric. However, I am stuck with this problem. Whatever I do, I can't get the desired result. The errors are caused by mainly "NA"s and "factor" data type. I will be very glad for any help Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would replace the "," to '."  using `sub`.  (`read.table/read.csv` have `dec` option as well).  Using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`, split the columns to two by specifying the sep as `,`.  The output will be `data.table`.  Create the "Total" column by using the `rowSums`.  If you want to return `NA` for rows that are all `NAs`, it is possible (one option is showed in the 2nd solution)

```
df$colname <- sub(',', '.', df$colname)
library(splitstackshape)
dt <- cSplit(df, 'colname', '+')
dt[, Total:=rowSums(.SD,na.rm=TRUE)][]
```

Or using `base R`, split the column ("colname") using `strsplit`.  Output will be a "list".  Convert the "character" to "numeric", pad `NAs` to get the length same in all the list elements and `rbind` (`df2 <- do.call(...,)`).  Create the "Total" column by `rowSums`, change the element to `NA` for those that are `NAs` in both columns.

```
 lst <- lapply(strsplit(df$colname, '[+]'), as.numeric)
 df2 <-  do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
     lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(sapply(lst, length))))
 names(df2) <- paste0('colname', 1:2)
 df2$Total <- (NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df2)))*rowSums(df2, na.rm=TRUE)
 df2
 #  colname1 colname2 Total
 #1     57.0      0.1  57.1
 #2     55.0       NA  55.0
 #3       NA       NA    NA
 #4     57.5      2.0  59.5
 #5     56.5      0.5  57.0
 #6     56.5       NA  56.5
 #7     58.0       NA  58.0
```

Or in this case, `eval(parse(` could also be used, which will avoid the step of changing `0` to `NA`

```
 df2$Total <- unname(sapply(df$colname,
                  function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
```

#### Update

If you need to replace the `NA` to `0` in "colname2"

```
df2$colname2[with(df2, is.na(colname2) & !is.na(colname1))] <- 0
 df2
 #  colname1 colname2 Total
 #1     57.0      0.1  57.1
 #2     55.0      0.0  55.0
 #3       NA       NA    NA
 #4     57.5      2.0  59.5
 #5     56.5      0.5  57.0
 #6     56.5      0.0  56.5
 #7     58.0      0.0  58.0
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(colname = structure(c(4L, 1L, NA, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
 6L), .Label = c("55", "56,5", "56,5 +0.50", "57 +0.10", "57,5 +2.00", 
"58"), class = "factor")), .Names = "colname", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: both code works very well. Your solutşon is very helpful not just for this problem, also for general understanding of R.

Comment: @akrun I think OP wanted 0s in `colname2` instead of `NA`s when `colname1` isn't `NA` (desired output)

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Thanks for the comment.  I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another idea.  You could take a step back and make use of the many arguments of `read.table()`.  Here we can use `sep = "+"`, since the function will strip the spaces between the columns.

```
df <- read.table(text = x, col.names = c("V1", "V2"),
    colClasses = c(V1 = "numeric", V2 = "character"),
    dec = ",", skip = 1, fill = TRUE, sep = "+"
)
```

So `V2` will be a character column with the `+` signs removed. So there are still a couple more steps to make the columns numeric and line up the NAs. For that we can use

```
within(df, {
    V2 <- replace(type.convert(V2), !nzchar(V2), 0)
    is.na(V2) <- is.na(V1)
    V3 <- V1 + V2
})
#     V1  V2   V3
# 1 57.0 0.1 57.1
# 2 55.0 0.0 55.0
# 3   NA  NA   NA
# 4 57.5 2.0 59.5
# 5 56.5 0.5 57.0
# 6 56.5 0.0 56.5
# 7 58.0 0.0 58.0
```

where `x` is

```
"colname\n57 +0.10\n55\nNA\n57,5 +2.00\n56,5 +0.50\n56,5\n58"
```

**Update / Improvement:**  You can also do this with `fread()` and the new `tstrsplit()` function available in 1.9.5. This also allows you to read the table from file without creating a data.frame first.

```
library(data.table)
fread(x, sep = "\n")[,
    tstrsplit(colname, "\\s?[+]", fill="0")][,
        lapply(.SD, function(x) type.convert(chartr(",", ".", x), as.is=TRUE))
    ][, V3 := rowSums(.SD)][]
#      V1  V2   V3
# 1: 57.0 0.1 57.1
# 2: 55.0 0.0 55.0
# 3:   NA 0.0   NA
# 4: 57.5 2.0 59.5
# 5: 56.5 0.5 57.0
# 6: 56.5 0.0 56.5
# 7: 58.0 0.0 58.0
```

Comment: @akrun, right.  All those arguments must have confused me.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  separate(colname, c("colname1", "colname2"), extra = "drop", convert = TRUE, '[+]') %>%
  mutate(colname1 = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", colname1)),
         colname2 = ifelse(is.na(colname1), NA, ifelse(is.na(colname2), 0, colname2)), 
         total = colname1 + colname2)
```

You get:

```
# colname1 colname2 total
#1     57.0      0.1  57.1
#2     55.0      0.0  55.0
#3       NA       NA    NA
#4     57.5      2.0  59.5
#5     56.5      0.5  57.0
#6     56.5      0.0  56.5
#7     58.0      0.0  58.0
```

That way you have 0s instead of `NA`s in `colname2` when `colname1` is not `NA`(as shown in your desired output)